# rails_admin using outdated table names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have two models connected with a has_and_belongs_to_many association: courses and semesters. rails_admin was only giving me the option to add semesters when creating a course, and not the other way around (and really, it's much more useful to add courses when creating a semester). I made some tweaks the migration:

```
  def change
    create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.string   "department"
      t.integer  "number"
      t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    end

    create_table "semesters", force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer  "year"
      t.string   "season"
      t.datetime "created_at", null: false
      t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end

    create_table "semesters_courses", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
      t.integer "semester_id"
      t.integer "course_id"
    end

    add_index "semesters_courses", ["course_id"], name: "index_semesters_courses_on_course_id"
    add_index "semesters_courses", ["semester_id"], name: "index_semesters_courses_on_semester_id"
  end
```

I renamed the intermediary table to semesters_courses from courses_semesters, just for clarity. Not only did this not solve the problem, but now when I try to add a new course, it 500s and tells me:

> Could not find table 'courses_semesters'

I know I could make this go away by changing the name back, but I'm not sure where railsadmin is getting that name from (and suspect this to be the source of my problem). I've removed and reinstalled railsadmin, dropped and rewritten the tables, and cleared my browser's cache. When I search my entire project tree for "courses_semesters," I only get results in my error log.

New at Rails dev, so I assume I'm missing some config file somewhere that I need to update, but would love some help on where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re overwriting the join table name.

**Option 1** you MUST specify the name of the join table in your models

**app/models/course.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :semesters, join_table: "semesters_courses"
```

**app/models/semester.rb**

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, join_table: "semesters_courses"
```

Or **Option 2** just rename your join table to "courses_semesters" by using migration.

```
rails g migration rename_courses_semesters

class RenameCoursesSemesters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :semesters_courses, :courses_semesters
  end

  def self.down
    rename_table :courses_semesters, :semesters_courses
  end
end
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believed I couldn't find that anywhere. Many thanks.